# How can I preview my app's name in the device app store?

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm planning to submit an app to the iOS App Store, and I'd like to choose a name that won't be truncated in the App Store on iPhone and iPod Touch. How can I check whether the name I've chosen will be truncated in the App Store?

Comment: You can't. But you can change the name when you update. Therefore I would try.

Comment: You need to guess what font the App store is using, then measure the name in points in that font.  For the device... You did test on your device one hopes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. However, you can estimate it by measuring the width of the text set in the same font as the App Store.

Comment: do you have any idea on how to reduce the height of the ipad app status bar in a storefront page which comes inside newsstand? -> the space between the app storefront and the, wifi signal, time and batteryleve, [http://www.techmynd.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/ios7-ipad-apps-1.png

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AddLingo StoreFront](https://storefront.localizedirect.com/) a free web app tool to preview in the browser what your iOS App Store presentation page will look like on the iPhone or iPad (disclosure - I created the tool).

Answer (score -1):

you can check the name in sinulator/test device. if it is not being truncated on simulator/test device then it will not be truncated.

Comment: You're probably right, but I suspect that some names which would be truncated by Springboard would not be truncated in the app store. My app title in Springboard is already different from my app's official name.

Comment: How can you review the appearance of you app in the app store before it is in the app store? Where is the app store on simulator?

Comment: bro..@dasdom there is no appstore simulator... but you can get a good idea from what I have suggested.

Comment: No you can't as Evan wants to know what happens in the app store. The appearance on springboard is already fixed.

Answer (score -2):

I would count the shown characters of other apps.

Comment: I don't think this will work because the App Store doesn't use a fixed-width font.

Comment: But you get a feeling for what happens there.